# Google API saying getRange(number,.....) not found

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to adapt some functionality from this tutorial for my own ends in AdWords.

This is the function I wish to use.

```
function getColumnsData(sheet, range, rowHeadersColumnIndex) {
  rowHeadersColumnIndex = rowHeadersColumnIndex || range.getColumnIndex() - 1;
  var headersTmp = sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), rowHeadersColumnIndex, 
  range.getNumRows(), 1).getValues();
  var headers = normalizeHeaders(arrayTranspose(headersTmp)[0]);
  return getObjects(arrayTranspose(range.getValues()), headers);
 }
```

However, on running I get the error message,

> Cannot find method getRange(number,number,number,number).

Which seems completely crazy. As far as I can see this [is core functionality for the adwords API.](http://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_sheet#getRange)

Am I missing something obvious? I'm passing 4 numerical parameters to `getColumnsData` when I call it, so even if the range is invalid, it should at least find the method, even if it can't execute properly.

Comment: Ah thanks for the edit, I missed the code blocks because I copied and pasted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a mistake on my part. This is not AdWords core functionality, but it is functionality for the Spreadsheets API. I have resolved this issue via another means now.